# Find all occurrences in a file with sed

Tags: sed

Using OPEN STEP 4.2 OS...
I am currently using the following `sed` Command:

```
sed -n '1,/141.299.99.1/p' TESTFILE | tail -3
```

This command will find one instance in a file with the IP of 141.299.99.1 and also include 3 lines before it which is all good, with the exception that I would also like to find all the instances of the IP and the 3 lines before it and not just the first.

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Unix, Linux, BSD, OSX, something else? Which version?

Comment: GREAT POINT! Using Open Step version 4.2 is quite old and the included shells don't include many of the features mentioned in the answers below.

Comment: Out of curiosity - what is an OPEN STEP 4.2 system and what is it used for today?

Comment: (and if Perl is available you can really do a lot of nice things just with that)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Maybe it's this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an attempt to emulate `grep -B3` using a sed moving window, based on [this GNU sed example](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#head) (but hopefully POSIX-compliant - with acknowledgement to @StéphaneChazelas):

```
sed -e '1h;2,4{;H;g;}' -e '1,3d' -e '/141\.299\.99\.1/P' -e '$!N;D' file
```

The first two expressions prime a multi-line pattern buffer and allow it to handle the edge case in which there are fewer than 3 lines of preceding context before the first match. The middle (regex match) expression prints a line off the top of the window until the desired match text has rippled up through the pattern buffer. The final `$!N;D` scrolls the window by one line except when it reaches the end of input.

Comment: `-e` is not GNU specific. To be POSIX/portable, you do _need_ it as there can't be anything after `}` (and you need a `;` before it).

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas - so are you saying that to be POSIX/portable, the first group needs to be split/modified as `-e '1h;2,4{H;g;}' -e '1,3d'`? I don't have a non-GNU system to test on (and the GNU sed `--posix` switch doesn't seem to care).

Comment: Yes, on Linux, you can test a different implementation with the `sed` from the heirloom toolchest which is a descendant of the traditional Unix sed. The POSIX/Unix spec for `sed` is at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html

Comment: I am getting event not found on either of these:            N;D': Event not found. Am I missing syntax somewhere? Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry I just realized my most recent edit omitted a closing single quote after the first -e expression. I have corrected it now - can you try again with the above expression please?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I like the compactness of the command but it comes back N;D': Event not found. I have checked my file and all the search criteria is there.

Comment: It sounds like your shell is trying to expand the `!` as a shell history command even though it's single-quoted - I don't know why that's happening. What shell/platform are you using?

Comment: ... I guess if `'$!N;D'` isn't working you could try backslash escapes i.e. `-e \$\!N\;D`

Comment: Very nice! That worked. One last question. If I wanted to have 9 lines before the pattern (IP) which variable would I tweak? Thanks so much! Dale

Comment: It _should_ just be a matter of changing `2,4{;H;g;}` to `2,10{;H;g;}` and `1,3d` to `1,9d` - however I haven't tested it.

Comment: Your a genius! Works great - thank you so much. I thought I could see what to change but it was hard for me to follow your buffer logic - your new update helps for any changes I'll have in the future. Very grateul for your time and efforts! Take care my friend!! Dale

Comment: You're welcome - fwiw I don't think anyone in their right mind would use `sed` for this if they had a modern version of `grep`

Answer (score 11):

`grep` will do a better job of this:

```
grep -B 3 141.299.99.1 TESTFILE
```

The [`-B 3` means](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Context-Line-Control.html#Context-Line-Control) to print the three lines before each match. This will print `--` between each group of lines. To disable that, use `--no-group-separator` as well.

The `-B` option is supported by [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Context-Line-Control.html#Context-Line-Control) and most BSD versions as well ([OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html), [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?grep), [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=grep), [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?grep)), but it is technically not a standard option.

Comment: Michael Homer - Thank you. I don't have the - B option. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Dale Can you install GNU grep? That will give you the option.

Answer (score 10):

With `sed` you can do a sliding window.

```
sed '1N;$!N;/141.299.99.1/P;D'
```

That does it. But beware - `bash`'s insane behavior of expanding `!` *even when quoted!!!* into the command string from your command history might make it go a little crazy. Prefix the command with `set +H;`if you find this is the case. To then re-enable it *(but why???)* do `set -H` afterward.

That, of course, would only apply if you *were* using `bash` - though I don't believe you are. I'm [fairly certain](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/14986-spawning-new-shells-command-line-openstep-4-2-a.html) you're working with `csh` - *(which happens to be the shell whose insane behavior `bash` emulates with the history expansion, but maybe not to the extremes the c shell took it)*. So [probably](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Quote.html#uh-0) a `\!` should work. I hope.

It's all portable code: [POSIX describes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html) its three operators thus: *(though it's worth noting that I've only confirmed this description existed as early as 2001)*

> `[2addr]N`
>   Append the next line of input, less its terminating `\n`ewline, to the pattern space, using an embedded `\n`ewline to separate the appended material from the original material. Note that the current line number changes.
>
> `[2addr]P`
>   Write the pattern space, up to the first `\n`ewline, to standard output.
>
> `[2addr]D`
>   Delete the initial segment of the pattern space through the first `\n`ewline and start the next cycle.

So on the first line you add an extra line to pattern space, so it looks like this:

```
^line 1s contents\nline 2s contents$
```

Then on the first line and every line thereafter - excepting the very last - you add *another* line to pattern space. So it looks like this:

```
^line 1\nline 2\nline 3$
```

If your ip address is found within you `P`rint up to the first newline, so just line 1 here. At the end of every cycle you `D`elete same and start over with what remains. So the next cycle looks like:

```
^line 2\nline 3\nline 4$
```

...and so on. If your ip is to be found on any one of those three the oldest will print out - every time. So you're always *only* three lines ahead.

Here's a quick example. I'll get a three line buffer printed for every number ending in zero:

```
seq 10 52 | sed '1N;$!N;/0\(\n\|$\)/P;D'

10
18
19
20
28
29
30
38
39
40
48
49
50
```

That one's a little more complicated than your case because I had to alternate from either `0\n` newline or `0$` end of pattern space to more closely resemble your problem - but they are subtly different in that this requires an anchor - which can be a little difficult to do since pattern-space constantly shifts.

I used the odd cases of 10 and 52 to show that as long as the anchor is flexible then so is the output. Fully portably, I can achieve the same results by instead counting on the algorithm and do:

```
seq 10 52 | sed '1N;$!N;/[90]\n/P;D'
```

And widen the search while restricting my window - from 0 to 9 and 0 and from 3 lines to two.

Anyway, you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for all your hard work. Sorry, where would I put the file name I would like it to search through?

Comment: @Dale - my bad. `sed '...' $filename`. By the way - I left in the periods from your own search string, but those aren't actually periods in a pattern - those represent any single character. You should probably do `oct\.oct\.oct\.oct` to escape them so they *only* match periods.

Comment: I tried to cat with it and different <> symbols and I get event not found which I get with other solutions here so I wonder if my OS isn't compatiable with these solutions.

Comment: now results with ->N;/141.299.99.1/P;D': Event not found.

Comment: @Dale - please see the update. It should help you.

Comment: Would you mind taking one more look. here is what I get with the new updates:sed '1N;$!N;/141\.299\.99\1/P;D' $TESTFILE
N;/141: Event not found.

Comment: @Dale - upon closer inspection - I don't believe `bash` is the problem - at least not *yours*. There's another update.

Comment: @Dale - I'm glad that though you didn't choose this answer you chose a portable and good answer. But I'm kinda dying to know - does this work with the bang backslash escaped in your shell? Can you do: `sed 1N\;\$\!N\;/141\.299\.99\.1/P\;D < /path/to/input/file`?

Answer (score 4):

Since [you mention](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146225/sed-command-line-question-to-find-all-occurances-in-a-file/146231#comment236314_146229) that you don't have the `-B` option to `grep`, you can use Perl (for example) to make a sliding a window of 4 lines:

```
perl -ne '
    push @window,$_;
    shift @window if @window > 4;
    print @window if /141\.299\.99\.1/
' your_file
```

[Ramesh's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146234/26909) does a similar thing with `awk`.

Comment: I am not sure if my version of Perl supports this but I will give it a try. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question - very grateful!

Comment: @Dale You're very welcome. I doubt that this code makes use of any cutting-edge Perl features.

Answer (score 4):

When available you can use [pcregrep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?pcregrep):

```
pcregrep -M '.*\n.*\n.*\n141.299.99.1' file
```

Comment: Checking into if I have PCREGREP. I like the compactness of the command. Very grateful for your time and efforts. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

You can implement the same basic approach as the other non-grep answers in the shell itself (this assumes a relatively recent shell that supports `=~`):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    [[ $line =~ 141.299.99.1 ]] && printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n" $a $b $c $line;
    a=$b; b=$c; c=$line; 
done < file
```

Alternatively, you could slurp the whole file into an array :

```perl
perl -e '@F=<>; 
        for($i=0;$i<=$#F;$i++){
          print $F[$i-3],$F[$i-2],$F[$i-1],$F[$i] if $F[$i]=~/141.299.99.1/
        }' file
```

Comment: My shell is very old - Steve Jobs Open Step. Great idea though and thank you for your time!!! Dale

Comment: @Dale the perl approach will work just about anywhere. Please tell us your operating system (add it to your question) that way we can suggest things that will work for you.

Comment: If I copy your Perl and put it into NotePad and put it on one line it works! Question - if I wanted lets say 10 lines before the match pattern where would I change the 3 to 10? Thanks!

Comment: I see that I can add more lines back by adding more $F[$i-X], statements. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If your system doesn't support `grep` context, you can try [ack-grep](http://beyondgrep.com/) instead:

```
ack -B 3 141.299.99.1 file
```

`ack` is a tool like grep, optimized for programmers.

Comment: I like the compactness of the command but my system doesn't support ack in looking in the man pages. Great idea and thank you so much for your time!!! Dale

Comment: @Dale: Suprising! What is your OS? If you have `perl`, you can use `ack`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/141.299.99.1/{for(i=1;i<=x;)print a[i++];print} {for(i=1;i<x;i++)
     a[i]=a[i+1];a[x]=$0;}'  x=3 filename
```

In this `awk` solution, an array is used which will always contain 3 lines before the current pattern. Hence, when the pattern is matched, the array contents along with the current pattern is printed.

**Testing**

```
-bash-3.2$ cat filename
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
10.0.0.4
141.299.99.1
10.0.0.5
10.0.0.6
10.0.0.7
10.0.0.8
10.0.0.9
10.0.0.10
141.299.99.1
10.0.0.11
10.0.0.12
10.0.0.13
10.0.0.14
10.0.0.15
10.0.0.16
141.299.99.1
10.0.0.17
10.0.0.18
10.0.0.19
```

After I execute the command, the output is,

```
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
10.0.0.4
141.299.99.1
10.0.0.8
10.0.0.9
10.0.0.10
141.299.99.1
10.0.0.14
10.0.0.15
10.0.0.16
141.299.99.1
```

Comment: so detailed - thank you very much. I'll give it a try. Very grateful for your time!! Dale

Comment: I have a test file and your solution works! The issue though is when I run it on my large production file it comes back with Too Long Record Number so the output is not able to work with the command. My original command at the top of this page works but only finds one instance. I appreciate your help. Is there anything I can do with my original command to make it find more than one instatnce?

Answer (score 1):

In most of these, `/141.299.99.1/` will also match (e.g.) `141a299q99+1` or `141029969951` because `.` in a regular expression can represent any character.

Using `/141[.]299[.]99[.]1/` is safer, and you can add additional context at the beginning and end of the whole regexp to make sure it doesn't match `3141.`, `.12`, `.104` , etc.

Comment: This is a good point - and one I also considered. Still, I used the string provided by the asker as a known working match - and notified him personally of the same when provided opportunity. Anyway - *not all* of these - [steeldriver's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146247/52934) has quoted the char match from the start.