# How do I extract the first integer from text string in a column of a tab-delimited file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk, columns

I work in Medical Genetics and often have delimited text files where in one column (ex. column 5) there is a text string with a "mutation" in our jargon:
`c.2458C>T` or
`c.45_46delAA` or
`c.749_754delinsTG`

Similarly, in another file it might read:
`p.Glu34*` or `p.Ala78_Arg80del` or `p.L378Ffs*11`

The `c.` and `p.` are supposed to be there but might be omitted. There could be any number of non-numeric characters. The numbers are always integers and usually 1-14 or so digits long.

I want to add a new column somewhere in my file, which has *only the first* integer, like 2458 or 45 or 749 in the first example. Then I want to use this integer as a key value for looking up several values in a lookup table.

Some of my files have 70,000 lines so manual editing is not possible...

The more basic the solution the better. Can it be done with bash, sed, or awk?

An example table would be (as interpreted correctly below):

```
1       2       3       4       c.2458C>T
a   b   c   d   c.45_46delAA
a1  b2  c3  d4  p.Ala78_Arg80del
```

(Note: the columns are tab-delimited, not space-delimited)

There is a specification to this format by the [Human Genome Variation Society](http://www.hgvs.org/mutnomen/). No program uses this format (I hope!) but people use it in publications and medical reports. Newer formats, like the [Variant Call Format](http://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.2.pdf) have been introduced, which are far more parsable.

Comment: Is `or` part of the text of the file, or are these 6 different examples of what the column might contain? It would help if you gave a few examples of full lines.

Comment: Is there some "specification" of this data format? Which program uses this format? If it is just the first integer, and it is always present, then this is probably easy to do (say, `sed -e 's/\([^[:digit:]]*\([[:digit:]]*\).*\)/\2;\1/'`, although I've probably missed some simpler way to write it)

Comment: Sorry @Gilles, I should have supplied an example table:

Answer (score 4):

Based on your description, suppose that we have, as input, a tab-separated file like:

```
$ cat file
1       2       3       4       c.2458C>T       6
a       b       c       d       c.45_46delAA or f
a1      b2      c3      d4      p.Ala78_Arg80del        f6
```

#### Using sed

To find the first integer from the fifth column:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^\t]*\t){4}[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+).*/\2/' file
2458
45
78
```

The above was tested on GNU `sed`.  For OSX or other BSD system, try:

```
sed -E 's/([^\t]*\t){4}[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*).*/\2/' file
```

#### Using awk

```
$ awk '{sub(/^[^[:digit:]]*/, "", $5); sub(/[^[:digit:]].*/, "", $5); print $5;}' file
2458
45
78
```

Answer (score 4):

Using @John1024's sample text, this is GNU-awk-specific

```
gawk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' 'match($5, /[[:digit:]]+/, m) {$(++NF) = m[0]} 1' file
```

produces

```
1   2   3   4   c.2458C>T   6   2458
a   b   c   d   c.45_46delAA    or  f   45
a1  b2  c3  d4  p.Ala78_Arg80del    f6  78
```

Or perl

```
perl -F'\t' -lane 'print join "\t", @F, $F[4]=~/(\d+)/' file
```

Comment: I want to wrap the gawk solution into a script like: #!/bin/bash

echo
read -p "Please enter your file name: " infile
echo
read -p "Please enter the column number with the mutations: " column
echo
read -p "Please enter a file name for the results: " outfile
gawk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' 'match($column, /[[:digit:]]+/, m) {$(++NF) = m[0]} 1' $infile > $outfile
*How do I pass a user defined variable like "$column" to gawk for the column to match?*

Comment: Like this : `gawk - F '\t' -v OFS='\t' -v col="$column" 'match($col, ...` - - you should add some verification the column variable is a number since awk handles non-number looking strings like the number zero so you could be matching against $0

Answer (score 4):

glenn jackman's GNU/AWK answer is elegant but a little more simply is

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} match($5,/[0-9]+/,arr) {print $0,arr[0]}' file
```

Comment: This also requires GNU awk for the three argument match() function

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` you can substitute by occurrence - so you just ask for the fifth *<`\t`ab>*-delimited <sup>***[1]***</sup> field and for any numbers within it by ruling out other possible matches:

```
sed 's/[^\t0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^\t]*/\1/5' <infile
```

After doing a copy to my clipboard of the other examples here I did:

```
xsel -bo | unexpand -a | sed ...
```

...to `unexpand` `-a`ll *<tab>*-sized space sequences into an actual *<tab>*. And it printed...

```
1   2   3   4   2458    6
a   b   c   d   45
a1  b2  c3  d4  78  f6
```

...which just isolates the first integer in the 5th column. I'm not sure if that's what you want, though. If you just want the first integer from the fifth column on a line all its own, that's far easier *(and much faster)*.

```
<infile \
 cut -f5 | tr -cs '0-9\n' \\t |
 expand -t1,2,4 | cut -d' ' -f-2
```

...which first `cut`s the fifth *<tab>*-delimited <sup>***[2]***</sup> field of data per line in full *(to avoid issues which may be caused by multiple integers per field)* and then `tr`anslates into a single *<tab>*  every `-s`queezed sequence of characters `-c`omplementary to the set of `\n`ewlines and `0-9` [standard digits](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap06.html) <sup>***[3]***</sup>.

This means that in the output the first integer will be in either the first or second field - because the first field is now either empty *(led by a <tab>)* or your digit sequence depending on whether it was prefixed as you note. So I `expand` the 1st and 2cd *<tab>*-stop positions on a line to a single space a piece, and the third to spaces - which effectively pads out a list of space-delimited fields into having either an empty first field or an empty third field. From there I can just `cut` out the first two fields.

```
 2458
 45
 78
```

...were my results for the example I used because they were all led by *[cp].* and so all had leading *<tab>* s but those without would be staggered to the left. To additionally condense all results to a single line with each integer separated by a single space you can just append `|xargs` to the command and get instead:

```
2458 45 78
```

***Notes***

1. Beware that the `\t` escape is not a standard one where `sed` is concerned - and in the context of a `[bracket-expression]` character class it is arguably even explicitly contrary to the standard as the `\`backslash and `t` characters should each represent themselves there. I have used the escape here to more clearly demonstrate a readable intent - but you should probably use a literal *<tab>* in its place.
2. `cut` delimits on *<tab>* characters by default, and so in this case the common `-d [delim-char]` option is unnecessary - but also added this note to explain why.
3. As is noted in the link, the POSIX-standard requires that the `[:digit:]` character class include the *0123456789* characters in all locales and in that sorting order and sorted ahead of any other inclusions in that class. Non C-locales may also include other localized numeral sets - which a GNU `tr` probably will not handle appropriately as they are likely represented by multiple bytes - but *only* the standard numeral set is more likely the least surprising result in most cases anyway, and so using `[:digit:]` unless you *definitely* want to match characters in both the standard Arabic numeral set and some *other* locale-dependent set of numerals is probably not advisable.

Comment: @don_crissti - well, if you're interested, the austin group has [marked as accepted](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=877) a request for standardizing `tail -r`, and so probably you'll be able to do that thing I remember you asking about for `tac` like `tail -rn [num-reversed-lines]` sooner than later.

Comment: @don_crissti - [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146238/52934)? That one was because the asker was actually using `csh` on an old *NeXTstep* system - though it wasn't apparent at first. In a `csh` shell the `!` can *only* be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: @don_crissti - I was wondering if you'd try [this](http://gdriv.es/mikeserv/scripts/null_paste.sh.html) out? It's still pretty rough, like I haven't yet got `--repeat` ironed out to keep all of the args in order - but `null_paste --head --sep 'any string' -ts'any string' file1 file2` should get the `-s` strings applied for every line in order for all named file arguments. `--head` or `--tail` or `-[ht]` will get the string at the head or tail of each line, and repeated occurrences of both or either will get it repeated as many times as they appear. Change the bangline to `/bin/sh -xf` maybe.

Comment: @don_crissti - yeah, back. I was [banned](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/is-there-any-onus-on-the-moderators-to-justify-their-actions#3502) for a week. I'd almost forgotten about that script. I have to look at it again... Strange you get an endless loop though - it seems weird that I would ask you look at it without at least verifying it didn't do that. I know that at one point it didn't - I was able to use it. I know also that before I quit playing with it a coupla weeks ago I had broken it pretty severely. I didn't think I altered the ver online though. I'll look again...